# Selecting a checkbox based on the value of the checkbox, when checkbox and label are two different elements

Tags: html, xpath, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

**I am trying to click on the checkbox present next to the label "Print Method 1".**

[This is how the element looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPeA8.png)

Here is the HTML code for the same:

```
            <div class="texter">
                <div class="checkbox"/>
                    <div title="Print Method 1">Print Method 1</div>
            </div>
```

I have the following xpath's so far:

```
$x("//div[@class='texter']//div[@class ='checkbox']//div[@title = 'Print Method 1']")

$x("//div[@class='texter']/div[@class ='checkbox']/following-sibling::div[@title='Print Method 1']")
```

It fails:

if i use the following xpath:

```
$x("//div[@class='texter']//div[@class ='checkbox']
```

I can select all the checkboxes present on the page, but how do i seperate the one where title is "Print Method 1".

Please assist, thankyou.

Comment: $x("//div[@class='texter']/div[@class ='checkbox'][div[@title = 'Print Method 1']]")

Comment: @splash58 thank you for the response, still no elements found.

Comment: you should try with..`$x("//div[@class='texter']/div[@class ='checkbox']/descendant::div[@title='Print Method 1']")`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
//div[@class='texter']//div[@class ='checkbox'][following-sibling::div[@title='Print Method 1']]
```

i.e. select the checkbox which has a following sibling whose title attribute is `Print Method 1`

Answer (score 0):

first one if class checkbox is paren,

second one if class checkbox is sibling

```css
//div[@title='Print Method 1']/../div[@class='checkbox']
//div[@title='Print Method 1']/preceding-sibling::div[@class='checkbox']
```